# Serverless.yml create of CloudFront with S3 origin and OriginAccessControl fail on first attempt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, serverless

I'm struggle with the setup of my CloudFront where i have a S3 Bucket as one of my Origin's. I would like to setup this origin with a OAC (OriginAccessControl). However, the first attempt to deploy fails.

If i commented out the S3 Origin and deploy (after removed the CloudFormation) it deploy's successfull. Once uncommented the S3 Origin and deploy again everything else is fine.

What is the way to not need uncomment this part and take it with me in the first deploy?

```
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          DefaultCacheBehavior: 
            ...
            CachePolicyId: 4135ea2d-6df8-44a3-9df3-4b5a84be39ad
            TargetOriginId: ApiGatewayV2
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          Origins:
            - DomainName: 
                Fn::Join:
                  - "."
                  - - Ref: HttpApi            
                    - execute-api
                    - ${self:provider.region}
                    - amazonaws.com
              Id: ApiGatewayV2
              CustomOriginConfig:
                  OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
            #- DomainName: ${self:custom.s3Bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com
            #  OriginPath: ""
            #  Id: S3-Bucket
            #  OriginAccessControlId: !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccesControl
            #  S3OriginConfig:
            #      OriginAccessIdentity: ''
          CacheBehaviors:
            #- PathPattern: /_static_folder/*
            #  TargetOriginId: S3-Bucket
            #  ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
            #  ForwardedValues:
            #      QueryString: true
            #  AllowedMethods:
            #    - HEAD
            #    - GET
            #    - OPTIONS
            #  CachePolicyId: 658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6
            #  Compress: true
```

The above will deploy successull. After commenting out the origin as below the S3 Origin will work also.

```
CloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          DefaultCacheBehavior: 
            ...
            CachePolicyId: 4135ea2d-6df8-44a3-9df3-4b5a84be39ad
            TargetOriginId: ApiGatewayV2
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          Origins:
            - DomainName: 
                Fn::Join:
                  - "."
                  - - Ref: HttpApi            
                    - execute-api
                    - ${self:provider.region}
                    - amazonaws.com
              Id: ApiGatewayV2
              CustomOriginConfig:
                  OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
            - DomainName: ${self:custom.s3Bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com
              OriginPath: ""
              Id: S3-Bucket
              OriginAccessControlId: !Ref CloudFrontOriginAccesControl
              S3OriginConfig:
                  OriginAccessIdentity: ''
          CacheBehaviors:
            - PathPattern: /_static_folder/*
              TargetOriginId: S3-Bucket
              ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
              ForwardedValues:
                  QueryString: true
              AllowedMethods:
                - HEAD
                - GET
                - OPTIONS
              CachePolicyId: 658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6
              Compress: true
`
```